# Declare string of dynamic length in C

Tags: arrays, dynamic

I have the following declaration: **char name[size + 1] = {'\0'};** where size has a predefined value. I don't want to fix the size of the Array. I want to know how to declare a string which will hold a name with dynamic lenth in C.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using malloc.

```
char* name = (char*)malloc((size+1) * sizeof(char));
```

Read about it [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_malloc.htm).

When you write `char name[size + 1]`, memory is allocated on stack. But with malloc it is allocated on the heap (dynamic memory).

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. 
char* name = (char*)malloc((size+1) * sizeof(char)); what should be the initial value of the variable 'size'?  

so I have a variable 'typeName' and a variable 'name'. The varaibale 'name' stores a string of characters in the following format: Auto_'typeName'_Workflow. The length of 'typeName' is determined at run time.

char name[name_size + 1] = {'\0'};
sprintf(name, "Auto_%s_Workflow", typeName);